# Timestamp troubles with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

so I just want to find wether a date is before today or a day in future. So basiclly I have this construction:

```
function data(startdate, enddate)
{
    var that = this;
    start = startdate;
    end = enddate;

    var today = new Date();
    today = today.getTime();
    today = Date.parse(today);

    this.status = false; // True = Server is in maintenance
    this.init = function()
    {
        isDone();
    }
    function isDone(){
        if( Date.parse(start) < today && today < Date.parse(end))
        {       
            that.status = true;
            console.log(that.status);
        }else
        {
            that.status = false;
            console.log(that.status);
        }
    }
}
```

Than I call it like this:

```
var x1 = new Date(2013,2,23,12,3,45);
var x2 = new Date(2013,2,27,12,3,45);

var foobar = new data(x1,x2);
foobar.init();
```

So tried to figure out, what javascript creates:

```
start:1364036625000 
end: 1364382225000 
today: 1361796935000
```

I also parsed it back into the standard format:

```
start:Sat Mar 23 2013 12:03:45 GMT+0100 
end:Wed Mar 27 2013 12:03:45 GMT+0100 
today:Mon Feb 25 2013 13:54:56 GMT+0100
```

So I have no idea, how to fix it or how it could work...

Comment: `today = Date.parse(new Date().getTime());` looks horrible. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Did you notice that `start` and `end` are in March?

Comment: Its purpose is to get the current time and parse it into seconds.

Nope I didn't noticed it :C big failure...

Comment: I guess you mean milliseconds. And you don't need to do that, it would be done automatically for Date objects when operating mathematically on them (`-`, `*`, `<`, …). And [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) expects strings, not Date objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't explicitly stated but you seem to forget (or ignore) that months are zero-indexed in javascript. February is `1`.

Comment: Most programmers working with dates in Java or JavaScript have been bitten by this indexing at least once...